# Can't create a tomcat server in visual studio code for mac

Tags: spring, tomcat, visual-studio-code

I installed tomcat;

```
brew install tomcat
```

And tried to put a server in VS Code by testing the folders that make sense of the folders shown by;

```
brew ls tomcat
```

But it still tells me "Please make sure you select a valid Tomcat Directory.".
Which is the right folder?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:

```
brew --prefix tomcat
```

Inside the returned path you have a directory called `libexec`.

That's the path you have to use.